# What was this hadith....that listener may understand it better than conveyor

Tags: hadith

I can't find it in English on google...

Basically it was like pass on the message because it's possible that listener may understand it better than conveyor.

I could be wrong. I am sure it was like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its part of the last sermon of our holy prophet (PBUH)

> I leave behind me two things, the Quran and the Sunnah (Hadith), and if you follow these you will never go astray. All those who listen to me shall pass on my words to others and those to others again; and **may the last ones understand my words better than those who listened to me directly**. Be my witness, O Allah, that I have conveyed your message to your people.

http://www.soundvision.com/info/hajj/lastsermon.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's also mentioned in a lot of ahadith narrated by a lot of sahaba () -apparently- not only in the last sermon and different wordings, but most seem to refer to that sermon as it's said that our Messenger (peace be upon him) said those words during a khutba, so you may find it in almost all hadith collections!

For example in Sahih [al-Bukhari, with the wording](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/3/9):

> It is incumbent upon those who are present to inform those who are
>   absent because those who are absent might comprehend (what I have
>   said) better than the present audience

an [other wording from Sahih al-Bukahri](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/29):

> O Allah! Be witness (for it). So it is incumbent upon those who are
>   present to convey it (this message of mine) to those who are absent
>   because the informed one might comprehend what I have said better than
>   the present audience who will convey it to him.

And in [Sunan at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/41/13) with the wording:

> 'May Allah gladden a man who hears something from us, so he conveys it as he heard it. Perhaps the one it is conveyed to is more understanding than the one who heard it.'

And ibn Majah [once with the wording](http://sunnah.com/urn/1302380):

> 'Let those who are present convey to those who are absent. For perhaps the one to whom it is conveyed will understand it better than the one who (first) hears it.'

and an [other time with a similar wording](http://sunnah.com/urn/1302370) to that of at-Tirmdihi!

An [other wording from at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/41/12) with another detail:

> ... Perhaps he carries Fiqh to one who is more understanding than him, and perhaps the one who carries the Fiqh is not a Faqih.

Fiqh here can refer to knowledge or wisdom ...!

And Allah knows best!